# Inserting sub-trees to a tree node

Tags: java, hierarchy

I have the following code (apologies it's a little long), which works:

```
public class Node {
        public String name;
        public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Node root = new Node();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestCreateHierarchy obj = new TestCreateHierarchy();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        List<List<String>> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] str = {"Person","Manager","Hourly","New"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str)) ;

        String[] str2 = {"Person","Manager","Salary","Hello"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str2)) ;

        String[] str3 = {"Person","Manager","Salary", "New"};
        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str3)) ;

//        String[] str4 = {"Person","Manager","Salary", "New", "John"};
//        objects.add(Arrays.asList(str4)) ;

        root.name = "ROOT";

        for (List<String> seq : objects) {
            LOG.debug("------------- NEW SEQUENCE -----------");
            LOG.debug(seq);
            LOG.debug("--------------------------------------");

            insert(seq);

//            break;
        }

        LOG.debug(root.children.size() + " <-- should be 1 ");

    }

    public Node createNode(List<String> seq, Integer start)
    {
        if (start >= seq.size())
            return null;

        Node node = new Node();
        node.name = seq.get(start);
        node.children.add(createNode(seq, start+1));

        return node;
    }


    public void insert(List<String> seq) {

        List<Node> children = root.children;

        // Where should we start to build the tree (how
        // deep into the sequence?)
        int start = 0 ;

        // Find the right place to add
        for (int i=0; i<seq.size(); i++) {
            boolean foundMatchingNode = false;

//            if (children.size() == 0)
//                continue;

            if (children.size() > 0) {
                for (Node node : children) {

                    LOG.debug("HERE --> " + node.name);

                    if (node.name.equals(seq.get(i))) {
                        children = node.children;
                        foundMatchingNode = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!foundMatchingNode) {
                children.add(createNode(seq,i));
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

My issue is that when I uncomment the `str4` part, I get a `NullPointerException` referring to the `insert` method, specifically to the `for (Node node : children)` part.

What do I need to change so that this code works with different hierarchy depths?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? (be specific ... explain what you expect the 'tree' to look like after each step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this function:

```
public Node createNode(List<String> seq, Integer start)
{
    if (start >= seq.size())
        return null;

    Node node = new Node();
    node.name = seq.get(start);
    node.children.add(createNode(seq, start+1));

    return node;
}
```

You are adding a child to each newly created node recursively and for the last function call where this condition `(start >= seq.size())` satisfies you create a `null` child.

So, after the insertion of str1, your tree looks like this:
`ROOT->Person->Manager->Hourly->New->NULL`. Now when you try to enter the str4 your logic for checking matching node name code comes into play. The loop runs fine for entries: **Person**, **Manager**, **Hourly**, **New** until it runs for the node which is `NULL`. In the inner for loop `for (Node node : children)` you have this debugger log: `LOG.debug("HERE --> " + node.name);`. It is at this point you're getting `NullPointerException` since your `node` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your createNode method is creating adding a null child to the leaf.  The NullPointerException occurs because the Node itself is null when you get to the bottom of the tree.

If this is not enough of a hint, please ask for more.